# Angularjs, watching scope variable in directive

Tags: angularjs, watch

From controller, I need to watch variable which is 2-way bound to directive scope.

As I tested in JsFiddle,
angular 1.1 works well, but angular1.2 does not.

How can I fix it?

http://jsfiddle.net/4091qg9r/3/

```
var simulationAppModule = angular.module('simulationApp', [])

simulationAppModule.controller('tst', function ($scope) {
    $scope.acts = [];


    $scope.$watch('acts', function (neww, old) {
        console.log('controller', neww)
    }, true)
})

simulationAppModule.directive('bn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            acts: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            $scope.addaction = function () {
                $scope.acts.push('aaa')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are declaring isolated scope in your directive, so `$scope.addaction` is never reached when you use `ng-click="addaction()"` on the directive element. ngClick and the `addaction` are in to different scopes.

One solution is not to use isolated scope, so you can remove

```
scope: {
    acts: '='
},
```

If you however do need the scope to be isolated child scope, then you can try (not recommended)

```
$scope.$parent.addaction = function () {
    $scope.acts.push('aaa')
}
```

But the best approach is to revise your set up, because `addaction` function should be declared **in controller**, not in directive.